# Discord.py Embed Local File

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I tried to add a file from my local device into a discord.py embed. Here's my code below, although its not working please help me

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command
async def pika(ctx):
  file = discord.File("‪E:\Python\discord.py\Pikachu1.jpg", filename="image.jpg")
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFFFFF)
  embed.set_image(url="E:\Python\discord.py\Pikachu1.jpg")
  await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what is not working here. Maybe you can also post a traceback?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you only set the color and add an image. Could it be that embed has required parameters? Try `embed = discord.Embed(color= 0xFFFFFF, title="test")`. Please add more info regarding what's not working as others have stated.

Comment: One more thing to try, change from `@client.command` to `@client.command()`

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a local file for an embed's image, use Discord's `attachment://` protocol. (Attribution to Lukasz).

```
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image